# Is it possible to add user defined elements to the XML output of Google Test?

Tags: xml, googletest

Is it possible to extend the XML output of Google Test with additional user defined elements?

It would make it easier to analyze the test-specific output of successfully run tests. By default, only the computational time in ms is placed as an element of the XML output.

The only information on the XML output I was able to find was [this](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Generating_an_XML_Report).

Comment: What more do you want to know of a successful test?

Comment: Im testing numerical algorithms, so i would like to write out the iteration count for example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into the function RecordProperty("key",value).

Source: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md